# Android chroot Debian

Tags: debian, embedded, chroot

I have a armv7l embedded device with 3 usb ports and a sd card slot.
The OS of the device is android with a Debian OS in chroot.

Via the Debian I can ssh into the device and breakout the chroot to the android kernel. No screen can be attached to the device.

I want to run Debian as the main OS and delete android all together.
Installing Debian is only possible with ssh which is not installed on the android OS.

Is it possible to somehow install Debian remotely via ssh without having any physical access to the device?